# Nginx Config with multiple vhosts and general part for every hosts

Tags: nginx, web-server, virtualhost, configuration

I have several subdomains in one configuration file.
I was wondering if is there a way to set a general configuration part for every hosts and then configure each host separately.

Like I have this listed in

sub1.domain.com

sub2.domain.com

sub3.domain.com

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 3d;
}
```

Is there any way to create a general part where I can list this only once and dont have to add to every section of the configuration?

Comment: look for include

Comment: Include would be to include an external config file, and not defining a portion of the same config file and re-using it. I am looking for some way to define something globally to the file and then list the various domain/site specific configs.

Comment: Still `include`. Write that portion to a file and include it.

Comment: But that's NOT WHAT I WANT! The reason why I keep the configs in one file because I don't want to manage multiple files for the same domain with all the subdomains.

Comment: for example i use for all domains the expire header i wrote a file expire. conf and include it and i only have to modify this file instead of every single host